# Metric in which $\mathbb{R}$ is not connected.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

I'd like to know. Is there a metric in $\mathbb{R}$ in which $\mathbb{R}$ is not connected?
Any hint about where could I find any info about that?

Comment: Yes. Put $\mathbb R$ in bijection with $(1,2)\cup (3,4)$. Transfer the metric.

Comment: Or, define the distance between two real numbers as $1$ unless they are equal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An example is $\mathbb{R}$ endowed with [discrete metric](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_space).