# Find a metric $d$ on $X$ such that $(X, τ^{(d/X)})$ is not connected

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

$X = (\{0\} \times [-1,1] \cup \{(x,\sin(π/x)) : x \in (0,1]\} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$

Find a metric $d$ on $X$ such that $(X, τ^{(d/X)})$ is not connected.

Note: $τ^{(d/X)}$ denotes the metric topology on $X$ with respect to distance, $d$.

Comment: I have tried to edit your post for better readability. But you should edit if further to get the post in the form you want. For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: If you have a set with more than 1 point, the _discrete metric_ will always induce a nonconnected topology. It is $d(x,y)=\begin{cases}0 \quad x=y\\1 \quad x\neq y\end{cases}$. In this case _every_ point is an open and a closed set, as such if there is more than 1 point then the topology will have more than 1 connected component.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $X$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb R$. (I.e., cardinality of $X$ is $|X|=\mathfrak c$.)

Take any metric space $(Y,\varrho)$ which is not connected and cardinality of the set $Y$ is $|Y|=\mathfrak c$. For example: [Metric in which $\mathbb{R}$ is not connected.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1157108/metric-in-which-mathbbr-is-not-connected)

Then you can use any bijection between $X$ and $Y$ to "transfer" the metric from $Y$ to the set $X$.

Comment: I'm confused. Can you be more specific please? What metric can be used to show this?

Comment: Did you have a look at the linked post? It mentions discrete metric, which is very simple. (But there are many other possibilities.)